# Guice and JDBC connection depending on credential

Tags: java, guice

I'm trying to Guice a class that returns a JDBC connection. 
The connection and credentials information can vary from one class to the other.

What's the easiest way to handle this problem in Guice ?

Ex:

a.java -> URL: localhost user: foo
b.java -> URL: remoteserver user: bar

Answer (score 0):

In Guice, you can use @Named annotation on constructors so that the correct values are injected into the object you want to be created, something like this:

```
@Inject
MyObject(@Named("jdbc.url") String jdbcUrl) {
    ...
}
```

Where do these come from? In your *Module class you need to load the properties, like this:

```
public class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
     @Override
     protected void configure() {
          // Handle exceptions, or this won't compile
          Properties properties = new Properties();
          ClassLoader loader = MyModule.class.getClassLoader();
          URL url = loader.getResource("my.properties");
          properties.load(url.openStream());
          Names.bindProperties(binder(),props);
          // Do the binding
          bind(bla).to(Bla.class);
     }
}
```